# How modify foreign key coinstraint to on delete cascade

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Basically, i have created this migration for my *child* table

```
 // ...
 $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
 $table->primary('project_id');
 $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('project');
 // ...
```

But i forgot to include `onDelete('cascade')`. How i can update this migration to add it?

Comment: just drop table and create a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Migrations are supposed to describe incremental changes to the database so that database schema can be versioned. **No past migration should be changed**, but if any changes are needed, a new migration file should be created that will apply necessary changes.

In your case, you'd need a new migration file that would drop the old constraint definition and apply a new one.  The following will do the trick:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddOnCascadeToProjectId extends Migration
{
  public function up()
  {
    Schema::table('your_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
      //drop the old constraint
      $table->dropForeign('your_table_project_id_foreign');
      //create new constraint with ON CASCADE
      $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('project')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
  }

  public function down()
  {
     Schema::table('your_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
       //drop new constraint with ON CASCADE
       $table->dropForeign('your_table_project_id_foreign');
       //recreate the old constraint
       $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('project');
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. But I guess, your code will throw an `Error: Undefined variable $table` in `down()` method.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the tip, copy-paste error. I've updated the answer